# Post-commit hook failed

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

We are working on sending email notifications of SVN commits and we are following the steps oulined here: http://sandilands.info/sgordon/email-notifications-of-svn-commits

When testing, we get following errors:

> Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 127) with output:
>   Error: /repos/cle/hooks/post-commit: 50: commit-email.pl: not found
>   Error: /repos/cle/hooks/post-commit: 51: log-commit.py: not found

Anyone wish to share their experiences?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it can't find (and thus cannot execute) commit-email.pl and log-commit.py.
You either need those in the path or specified with a full path when calling (as well as making sure you even have these).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at my [SVN Watcher](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Watcher-Hook) post-commit hook script. It will send out an email on commit, but will allow you to configure your *watch* to specify what files you're interested in. Plus, all users can create a watch list of files they're interested when a commit happens.

The error message is pretty straight forward: It can't find the the named scripts (and you probably only want to use the Perl version or the Python version, but not both. The error could be caused by multiple issues:

- Incorrect `PATH` set. Subversion mucks with the environment and shell variables may not be set. This includes `PATH` which might be set to a default value.
- The Perl and Python script may not have the executable bit set for the user who is executing the hook.
- The Perl and Python script may have a bad processor line (for example, Perl is installed in `/usr/bin/perl`, but your first line is `#! /usr/local/bin/perl`).
- The Perl or Python interpreter may not be in your path.

If `post-commit` is a shell script, add `set -xv` and `export PS4="\$LINENO:` on the top. This will print out debugging information, so you can see what's going on in your script. This will only print out if the shell script fails.